# Run exe from its folder

Tags: c#, process, executable, wkhtmltopdf

this is my scenario: I have an executable file that convert html files to pdf.
This exe work only if you start it from its folder.
Example: the exe is in C:\HtmlToPdf, so, in the prompt I will do this:

```
C:\> cd HtmlToPdf
C:\HtmlToPdf> htmltopdf.exe htmlFile pdfFile
```

So, there is a way to do this in c#? Because I tried this:

```
FileInfo htmlInfo = new FileInfo(executablePath + @"\" + filename);
var procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("wkhtmltopdf.exe",htmlInfo.FullName + " " + htmlInfo.FullName.Replace(".html",".pdf"));

procInfo.WorkingDirectory=executablePath;
procInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(procInfo);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: I added a tag so your question is more google friendly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[wkhtmltopdf's documentation/wiki](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/Usage) states that it will struggle to find a file if you use its full path. You need to append `file:///` to the beginning of the file name

> Note that on Windows, you can't use absolute path names with drives for HTML files at the moment:
>
> wkhtmltopdf d:\temp\x.html x.pdf
>
> will fail. You need to rather use file:/// URLs:
>
> wkhtmltopdf file:///d:/tmp/x.html x.pdf

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546420/1324033) may help in the appending

Comment: It works like with the Aravind answer, but the images aren't shown in the pdf, there is only a white square where the image should be.

Comment: Yeah I had that problem also but can't remember how I resolved it.. I think I  set the working directory of the process to the folder where the html page was, the reason it does it is the html has local paths to the images

Comment: I solved it! the solution was to pass like argument only the name of the arguments, not the full path! Thank you anyway!

Comment: No worries, like the first line of my answer says "it will struggle to find the file if you use its full path" :)

Answer (score 0):

From where you are calling the EXE .. .whether its Windows Form application or Webforms....

```
If its windows forms it will work

else

if its Webforms like asp.net you have to change the properties of IIS Server to start the exe

Because due to some security reasons microsoft will not allow you to start the process class from IIS server... but the same code will work from Visualstudio ..
```

Here is my code

To get Current Exe Executable path

```
 string sCurrentPAth =  Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

  Process.Start(@"E:\Debug\MyExe.exe", "arg1 arg2 arg3");
```

Its Working Correctly .....

Comment: Can you let me see the piece of code in the html file where the images are refered? Because in my html the image are in this code: <img src="TEST\image1.jpg"> and it is in C:\htmlToPdf\TEST and the exe is in C:\htmlToPdf and it, from c#, doesn't work @AravindSrinivas

Comment: Actually what you need ... Do you want to start the exe by passing the arguments using process class or.. do u need to convert Html to Pdf ....I mean whats your real problem... ?

Comment: I have simplified my code first try this and run your exe whether your exe it is taking arguments or not ???