# C# .NET MediaPlayer can't use relative URL

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm developing a retro-style game in `C#` `.NET-Framework`, and I would like to use different sounds and music in my game. But I have a problem. The original *System.Windows.Media.SoundPlayer* doesn't support 2 (or more) sounds being played. When one starts, it stops the active one.

I'm looking for a solution that can play different audio at the same time. I tried threading the different SoundPlayers to different threads, but that wasn't a good solution for me (+ it didn't work).

I read about *System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer*, and the different controls that you could use with it. This instantly had me interested, especially after I read that you could play different sounds at once.

But trying to use the MediaPlayer in my game, it throws an error, because the URL isn't spelled correct. Here is my code:

```
    using System.Windows.Media;

    MediaPlayer Sound = new MediaPlayer();
    MediaPlayer BackgroundMusic = new MediaPlayer();
    
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Sound.Open(new Uri("Text1.wav"));
        BackgroundMusic.Open(new Uri("BackgroundMusicMix.wav"));
    }
    
    private void BtnSound_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Sound.Play();
    }

    private void BtnBackgroundSound_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundMusic.Play();
    }
```

The .wav-files are here located in the `\bin\debug` folder of my solution, because the SoundPlayer also gets it's sounds from there. I am aware of the fact that you can always put in the full filepath, but the project is being edited by multiple people, so we need the sounds to be located in the solution folder (*relative URL*).

SO my question is: what is the correct spelling for relative URL? Or even better, is there a simpler method to play 2 sounds simultaneously?

Comment: The issue with the "relative URL" you're seeking is that it'd be relative _to what_?  This is a compiled application, not a web page, so neither `Uri` nor `MediaPlayer` can assume the answer to that (particularly since it appears you're hosting a WPF control in WinForms).  That you don't want to hard-code an absolute URL doesn't mean you can't construct one (path to `Debug` + `BackgroundMusicMix.wav`) at runtime.

Comment: @BACON It'd be relative to the application itself, but I understand what you're saying. But how would you code the path to debug then?

Comment: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` will get you the absolute path to the `.exe` file, then `Path.GetDirectoryName()` to get the path of the containing directory, then `Path.Combine()` with `"BackgroundMusicMix.wav"` to get the sound file path, then create a `Uri` out of that.

Comment: string fullURI = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "BackgroundMusicMix.wav"); // this code seems to be working. thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the "relative URL" you're seeking is that it'd be relative *to what*?  This is a compiled application, not a web page, so neither `Uri` nor `MediaPlayer` can assume the answer to that.

That you don't want to hard-code an absolute path doesn't mean you can't construct one at runtime, though.  You can use the [`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly) to get the absolute path to your application...

```cs
string executableFilePath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

...and then use the [`Path` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path) to turn that into an absolute path to your audio file...

```cs
string executableDirectoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(executableFilePath);
string audioFilePath = Path.Combine(executableDirectoryPath, "BackgroundMusicMix.wav");
```

...from which you can create an absolute `file` URL...

```cs
Uri audioFileUri = new Uri(audioFilePath);
```

See [Convert file path to a file URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1546419/150605) for some of the peculiarities to consider when constructing a `Uri` from a filesystem path like that.

By the way, as far as alternatives, I've not used this myself so I don't know how suited it is for what you're doing, but I know [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) is a thing that exists.