# Convert network Path containing a "@" to URI

Tags: c#, .net, uri

i want to convert a network path (Directory "\www.dummy.com@ABC\test") to URI:

```
var uri = new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

It occures a URIFormatException

How can i fix this?

Comment: Maybe this can help u: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546419/convert-file-path-to-a-file-uri

Comment: Unfortunately this page doesn't get me any further

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change `UriKind` enum to the `Relative` value.
This code snippet is working fine:

```
const string path = @"\www.dummy.com@ABC\test";
var uri = new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative);
Console.Write(uri);

// Output:
// \www.dummy.com@ABC\test
```